# JQuery toggle doesn't work on change when I try to set css

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have a toggle button that works only once. This is the portion of script:

```
$('#toggle').change(function(){

    var mode= $(this).prop('unchecked');

    if(mode = true) {

      $('.container').css('display','block'); 
      $('.container').hide().delay(500).fadeIn(1000); 
      $('#map').css('filter','grayscale(100%)');

    } else {

      $('.container').css('display','none'); 
      $('.container').delay(500).fadeOut(1000); 
      $('#map').css('filter','grayscale(0%)');

    }

});
```

The first part of If condition is fired, not the Else part. I don't understand why. Some help?

Comment: Hi, please poste your code to jsbin or jsfiddle

Comment: Try if(mode. == true) instead of if(mode = true).

Comment: @matthias_h doesn't work :(

Comment: @albreik Please add HTML content of the code to get better idea. It's unclear if on click you're changing the CSS or it's a checkbox. Please add more description.

Comment: Hi, Try using this: `if ($(this).is(":checked")) { // code here...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors in you code.
1) There is no such property as :unchecked, you should use :checked property
2) You have written if(mode = true) not if(mode == true), so you didn't check equality, you assign new value

There is right code:

```
$('#toggle').change(function(){

var mode= $(this).prop('checked');
console.log(mode);

if(mode == true) {

  $('.container').css('display','block'); 
  $('.container').hide().delay(500).fadeIn(1000); 
  $('#map').css('filter','grayscale(100%)');

} else {

  $('.container').css('display','none'); 
  $('.container').delay(500).fadeOut(1000); 
  $('#map').css('filter','grayscale(0%)');

}

});
```

Comment: And you should use jsbin or jsfiddle for such questions. It will boost your chance to get answer

Comment: no, they should use a snippet in the question.  But only for working code to demonstrate the problem.  A fiddle with just the code provided would be of no use neither would an in-question snippet.  OP provided the correct amount of code in the correct format for you to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

A couple issues here. @AidOnline01 mentioned the first two.

1. Property `unchecked` doesn't exist, use `checked` instead.
2. `if (mode = true)` statement assigns `mode` a value instead of evaluating equality. Use `if (mode == true)`
3. Fade out function doesn't wait for animation to complete before assigning. Use a callback to call `$('.container').css('display','none');`

I've made a JSFiddle to demonstrate:
https://jsfiddle.net/g3y27o5L/4/

Comment: 3. you don't need to hide something once it's already hidden (via fadeout) so the callback is useless.  Correct that OP had it round the wrong way (hide then fadeout also does nothing).